# SPSS - converting TABLES to CUSTOM TABLES with Syntax Converter

Tags: spss

I have prepared some functions to generate tables in SPSS but at this moment I have to convert all these tables to Custom Tables. I found out that I can use SPSS Syntax Converter script instead of writting a new code from the beginning, which will change code related to tables and provide appropiate custom table counterpart. On IBM website I found informations about limitations of this method, I tried to change variable names in my code and delete, but every time i get only an error. What should I change in my table syntax to have functional Syntax Converter? What shape should it have? Below is my example.

```
DEFINE !TABLE (!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)/!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)/!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)/!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)/!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)/!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos = !tokens(1) /!pos= !tokens(1)).


TEMPORARY.
VARIABLE LABELS !1 ''.
 TABLES /Format BLANK MISSING('.') 
 /GBASE=CASES 
 /PTOTAL= $t000002 '$/Total'  $t000001 '$/Total' 
 /TABLE=$t000002 + !1 BY $t000001+ !2+ !3+ !4+ !5+ !6+ !7+ !8+ !9+ !10 
 /STATISTIC count( !1( F5.0 )'$$Count') cpct( !1( F5.2 ) '$$Column-%': !2 !3 !4 !5 !6 !7 !8 !9 !10) cpct( !1( F5.2 ) '$$Row-%':!1)
 /TITLE = !11 !ENDDEFINE.
```

Comment: This is a macro definition (which actually seems to have a few problems) that won't do anything in itself - didn't you also find an explanation about calling the macro? you might post the link to the source for us to see too. In any case I'm not sure what is meant by "syntax converter" - what the macro would do once it's fixed and you know how to call it, is to receive a short command (the macro call, some variable names and a title) and create the same table as the full command structure would.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I pasted everything, but this Tables Syntax Converter script should work after pasting the part only related to the table (part of the code from TABLES, we can ignore macro). There's the link to IBM website http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477153.